# Find $r$, given that $F_r= 2F_{101}+F_{100}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

> Find $r$, given that $F_r= 2F_{101}+F_{100}$.

We know that the recurrence relation for the Fibonacci sequence is $F_n= F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ and that $F_0 = F_1 = 1$, but how to proceed further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F_{103}=F_{102}+F_{101},\quad F_{102}=F_{101}+F_{100}\quad \implies \quad F_{103}=2F_{101}+F_{100}$$

Comment: So is it just adding the first coeffecient to the first subscript ? Or something else i need to understand?

Comment: @Pradeep The thing you need to understand is that the recurrence relation holds for all $n$ (well, for $n \ge 2$) and that you can *use* this fact.  Since you didn't know how to proceed it's likely you had not internalized this (e.g. quoting the recurrence without thinking about what it really means).  From your response I'm still not sure that you have...

Comment: Yes.I just started recurrence relations.I did not comprehend the topic yet.I am still in the beginning of the chapter in my book.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the relation,

$$ F_{n} = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} $$
$$ F_{n+1} = F_{n} + F_{n-1} $$
$$ \rightarrow F_{n+1} = [F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}] + F_{n-1} $$
$$ F_{n+1} = 2 \cdot F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} $$

You could do this as many times as you like and get to the expression of any number in the sequence in terms of the 2 first ones.